# styles stop working after adding version to elixir

Tags: laravel, laravel-elixir

In Laravel, I’ve in `public/css/app.css` the following:

```css
body { background: "red"; }
```

It’s linked to my layout like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
```

But when I go to the home page, the style isn’t applied to the body. I checked the source and the CSS file is there!

I removed the cache but nothing happened. This problem start after I added `version()` to elixir but after that I removed all the build folder, now I can’t get the style working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `version()` in elixir the filename changes. You can add following helper

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}">
```

this will always return the correct file name.

Refer to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#versioning-and-cache-busting) for versioning and cache busting.

Also make sure you run the `gulp` command again since you deleted the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `asset` to refer/link to files in public folder

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/css/app.css')}}" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write this. This is Laravel predefined Function

```
{{ HTML::style('css/app.css'); }}
```